# How to calculate $ \int ^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \frac{1}{ 3\sin{x}+\cos{x}+15}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need some help to calculate this integral.

$$ \int ^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0} \frac{1}{ 3\sin{x}+\cos{x}+15}dx $$

I have no idea how i should act, but I think that in this case the best way is trying with substitution or trying to separate the original integral into two other different pieces.

Any hints to start?

Comment: Have you tried the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Tangent half-angle substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)?

This simplifies the integrand into

$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{8+3t+7t^2}
$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I think this is definitely what i was looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GabrieleSalvatori. Always think about this method for this kind of integrals. It solves a lot of problems.